# insert data into specific column cell using datatables jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've searched into the documentation of data tables of how one can add data to the table here 
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/index.html but no where I could find a way to insert data into a single cell for a given column. For example, I need sth like:

```
 "columns": [ {target (0), "value which will be inserted"} ]
```

There is a way to inser data from an array but each section of the array contains values for the whole row ( see here https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) but I need to insert data into different cells in respect with the columns since I don't know the column labels initially. This is because the data will be in json format and first I need to extract the unique dates for each json object. These will be my column headers. And then for each of the objects based on its date I need to put it into the relevant date column. So the logic should be sth like:

```
 if this date column (from the table) == json object date then put it there
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us some part of your table, and the array which you want to set

Comment: The data will be in json format and first I need to extract the unique dates for each json object. These will be my column headers. And then for each of the objects based on its date I need to put it into the relevant column.

Comment: Could you also paste the construct of your table

Comment: I've got no table construct as yet. I am just thinking of the way I am gonna do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like after a lot of researching this feature is not available in DataTables. So that's why I've solved the problem with jQuery. Using the code below I can iterate through a column and insert values in it.

```
//change 1 to the column at hand
$("#table tr > :nth-child(1)").each(function(index) {
    //skip the column header
    if (index > 0){
        //insert value
        $(this).html("<span class='fixed-size-square'> value to be inserted");
    }
});
```

Comment: use the api to set/get data. Your approach will fail if any sorting or paging is done as the plugin won't recognize your html changes. See https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.data%28%29